# How to move html source code to a different location in page using dreamweaver

Tags: html, dreamweaver

I need to move a selection of html code to a different location in a web page
Using find and replace in dreamweaver does not work

For example:

```
     <div id="popups">
      <div id="pop1">
        <div class="clean-graypop" id="pop1content"><b>Vector</b><br/>
A living carrier, such as an insect, that transports an infectious agent from an infected individual to a susceptible individual.</div>
      </div></div>
```

I want to move this code to a completely different location (in our case, bottom of the html page).

I have hundreds of html pages with these styled popup divs but differing text content.

I want to be able find them all and move them

I found that I can target these divs using regex code /*[\w\W]**/

This works if I use comment tags to surround the code of interest. The regex code basically find the text within those comment tags

However, there no way in find&replace that I know where I can move the found source code to a different location

Basically I want a find and move action

Any ideas

Thanks
Jon

Comment: Do a search for creating a macro - you may be able to make one to do what you want